# Об орфографической зоркости (по мотивам сочинений Людмила)

Tags: орфография

Я не отрицаю, что почти ничего не знаю и почти ничего не умею. Поэтому некоторые сведения, излагаемые местными знатоками русского языка, воспринимаются мной как сочинения алхимиков.

**Вопрос:** Изменится ли орфографическая зоркость учащихся, если изъять из русского алфавита знак "ъ"?

P.S.

1. Словосочетание "орфографическая зоркость" найдено мной в одном из ответов участника Людмила.
2. Допускаю, что ответ на мой вопрос может иметь вид: "Орфографическая зоркость учащихся значительно возрастёт, если убрать знак "ъ" из русского алфавита."
3. Я не сомневаюсь, что русским детям удобнее слышать и писать слово "изйан", чем слышать "изйан", а писать "изъян".
4. Также не сомневаюсь, что простенькая программа, добавленная в текстовой редактор, позволяет перекодировать слова с буквосочетаниями "ъя", "ъе", "ъё", "ъю" в слова с  буквосочетаниями "йа", "йэ", "йо", "йу" соответственно.
5. Лица, желающие продемонстрировать свою эрудированность, могут ответить на вопрос: "Изменится ли орфографическая зоркость грамотных русскоязычных пенсионеров, если изъять из русского алфавита знак "ъ"?

Answer (score 4):

При любой реформе письма количество пишущих грамотно резко уменьшается, затем, через 20-30 лет восстанавливается на прежний уровень. Причин у этого явления две:

1. Нет достаточного количества безошибочно написанной литературы на новой грамматике.
2. Нет достаточного количества подготовленных кадров, для преподавания новой грамматики.

Поэтому все реформы алфавита проводятся лишь в случаях крайней необходимости, если это экономически оправдано. В частности при реформе 1918 года, за счёт изъятия еров, значительно сократились расходы на бумагу, и время на обучение базисному письму. Последний факт, в условиях гражданской войны и послужил причиной реформы.

Ваш вариант рефрмы (убрать *я, ю, е, ё, ъ* и разделительный *ь*) даже при условии уменьшения обучения базисному письму, приведёт к удоражанию печатной продукции, так как *мять* короче чем *мьать*, а соответственно экономически нецелесообразно.

Comment: 1. Вы не ответили на мой вопрос об "орфографической зоркости".

2. Я сомневаюсь в достоверности некоторых предоставленных Вами сведений, начиная с предложения "При **любой** реформе письма ..."

3. Я не сомневаюсь, что "мять" короче, чем "мьать".

Comment: 1. Вам известны статистические методы выявления грамотности врождённой, но не приобретённой? Если да, буду рад с ними ознакомится.  
2. Сомневайтесь. Заодно можете посмотреть результаты недавней реформы немецкой грамматики.